# How to use vue3 three.js and typescript load vtk files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, three.js, vtk

I used this code bug have some bugs.

```
import { VTKLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/VTKLoader';      
const loader = new VTKLoader();
      loader.load('./temperature0.vtk',
        (geometry: any) => {
          geometry.computeVertexNormals();
          const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
          const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
          scene.add(mesh);
        }
      );
```

> TypeError: THREE.BufferAttribute: array should be a Typed Array.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCaAv.png)]

I hope read this vtk file and show it.